# Blackberry Widget: Where is the www folder on the device?

Tags: blackberry, widget, cordova

Where do the files I put in the "www" directory before building a Blackberry widget end up on the device?

Background: I would like to read the content of some of the files (e.g. "www/index.html") from the www directory in the native Java part of the widget. (I already used FileConnection.list to write the name of all files on the device to System.out - neither index.html nor any other file from the www directory was part of the list.)

The widget is based on PhoneGap 0.9.4 for Blackberry but that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: The files are packaged as resources. Therefore it's possible to read them with Class.getResourceAsStream.

Example:
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/index.html");